# Remove duplicates, with "cookie crumbs" to remember why it was removed

Tags: r, unique, duplicates

I have a dataset with ~500,000 rows and 45 columns.  I want to remove rows that are duplicates of each other, as the R "unique()" function does (keep the first occurrence, remove the rest), but for each row that was removed, I would like to store which row that I kept it is equal to.

I'm going to say the same thing another way because I feel like this is a little hard to explain.  For each set of identical rows in my dataset (call that S), I want to keep only one of them in the dataset (call the kept one K).  And I want to discard the other size(S)-1 identical rows (call them D).  For each element in D, I would like to know the index of K.

I am able to do this with for loops, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way with unique(), duplicated(), and the like.  Note that I use the variable name "pioneers" to mean K and "dupes" to mean D, and "dupes.i" to mean the indices of D.

```
pioneers <- unique(genos.varying)
dupes.i <- duplicated(genos.varying)
dupes <- genos.varying[dupes.i,]

# note -- look at the rowname of the pioneer to see where it was in the 'original' dataset
which.pioneer.by.dupes <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=nrow(dupes))

for(d in 1:nrow(dupes)) {

    for(p in 1:nrow(pioneers)) {

        if (all(pioneers[p,] == dupes[d,])) {

            which.pioneer.by.dupes[d] <- p
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice you can offer!

Also, here's a practice dataset, in case that makes it easier for people to work with:

```
genos.varying <- matrix(c(1,2,3,7,6,4,1,2,3,4,3,6), ncol = 3, byrow=TRUE)
```

The output should be something along the lines of:

```
Keep rows 1,2, and 4.  Row 3 is a duplicate of row 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using a hash by row:

```
library(digest)
g <- matrix(c(1,2,3,7,6,4,1,2,3,4,3,6, 1,2,3, 7,6,4), ncol = 3, byrow=TRUE)
df <- as.data.frame(g)
df$digest <- apply(g,1,digest)

keep <- sort(as.integer(by(df, df$digest, function(x) rownames(x)[1])))
cat('keeping rows ', paste0(keep, collapse=', '), '\n')

res <- by(df, df$digest, function(x) {
    set <- sort(as.integer(rownames(x)))
    if (length(set) > 1)
      cat('row(s) ', paste0(set[-1], collapse=', '), ' are duplicates of row ', set[1], '\n')
    set
 })
```

input is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    7    6    4
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    4    3    6
[5,]    1    2    3
[6,]    7    6    4
```

output is:

```
keeping rows  1, 2, 4
row(s)  6  are duplicates of row  2 
row(s)  3, 5  are duplicates of row  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This definitely works.  But I wonder if there's something slicker that uses the unique() or duplicated() functions.  It seems like those functions must be figuring out the answer to my question internally.